# Admin action- queryset to apply Many to Many

Tags: django, django-admin, django-queryset, django-admin-filters

How do I use the admin action to create a queryset which will apply a Many-to-Many value?

I understand the 'value' will have to already exist (in my case, the colour itsel will have to exist).

Models

```
class Colours(models.Model):
    colour_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Car(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    available_colours = models.ManyToManyField(Colours, blank=True)
```

Admin.py

```
class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = ['Red']
```

Attempt 1: only works for FK

```
def Red(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(colour=Colour.objects.get(colour_name__iexact='Red'), updated=timezone.now())
```

Attempt 2: Did not work

```
def Red(self, request, queryset):
    queryset.update = self.model._meta.app_label, self.model._meta.model_name
```

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Use an admin action (dropdown menu), apply an m2m relations (in this case, the colour "RED") to a ticked object. Similar what you can do with django Admin to "delete" multiple objects, I'd like to use that area to add my this custom action.

Comment: so you want to make all cars red which are ticked?

Comment: Exactly. Apply it to all the models ticked. If the car is already "RED" it can ignore it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can [assign relations sets in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

```
def Red(self, request, queryset):
    red_color = Colour.objects.get(colour_name__iexact='Red')
    queryset.update(available_colours=[red_color])
```

according to your comment and to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once), it seems django doesnot support bulk update for manytomany fields.

you can solve it this way:

```
def Red(self, request, queryset):
    red_color = Colour.objects.get(colour_name__iexact='Red')
    for car in queryset:
        car.available_colours.add(red_color)
```

Comment: This says "Cannot update model field <django.db.models.fields.related.ManyToManyField: category> (only non-relations and foreign keys permitted).". This is basically my example from above. Here's the traceback (note, I'm using Category where my example wanted colour) http://dpaste.com/3QJE6JV

Comment: ah, then bulk update doesnot support this. I will update my answer

Comment: Almost! This works, but removes any M2M's that already exist (ie removes all other colours that relate to car I add "red" to). How is this fixed?

Comment: Thank you. What will happen if I try to apply the colour, and a car already has that colour relation? will it add it twice or ignore?

Comment: @yian you can assign multiple times. Not sure if it ignores but supposed to. Please try it and let me know

Comment: I dont want it to assign it multiple times. I want it to ignore adding the value if it already exists.